# Can subsetting the output dataset mess with the merge data step in SAS?

Tags: merge, sas

While merging two datasets using the `merge` statement, is it fine to subset the output dataset while it is being created?

In a nutshell, which of the two approaches is better?

A)

```
data merge_output;
 merge
       merge_input1 (in = ina)
       merge_input2 (in = inb)
 ;
 by some_column;
 if ina and inb;
 if some_other_column eq 'Y' then output merge_output;
 else delete;
run;
```

B)

```
data merge_output (where = (some_other_column = 'Y'));
 merge
       merge_input1 (in = ina)
       merge_input2 (in = inb)
 ;
 by some_column;
 if ina and inb;
run;
```

In my experience, I have seen a situation where using approach A led to erroneous merge, whereas approach B is a sure shot success. I was trying to explain this to a wider team, but could not find any documentation.

I believe that deleting rows or sub-setting the dataset while it is being created in a merge statement somehow screws up the merge process running in the background. Can someone help me with the explanation or the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither!  If you must use a Data step then your WHERE data set option should be used earlier rather than later.  I have assumed that some_other_column is already in merge_input_table1.  If it is in the other table then move/copy as is appropriate.

The WHERE data set option and statement filters unwanted rows of data.  This reduces processing as unwanted rows are excluded from the PDV.

```
data merge_output ;
 merge
       merge_input1 (in = ina where = (some_other_column = 'Y'))
       merge_input2 (in = inb)
 ;
 by some_column;
 if ina and inb;
run;
```

Using the Data Step to perform merges as you point out risks unexpected results.  Filtering can become implicitly entangled in processing leading to unintended results.  SQL is far less risky as it is explicit.  You define what you want and the SQL engine will determine the best way to get it.

```
proc sql;
    create table merge_output as
    select * 
    from   merge_input1 
    inner  join
           merge_input2
    on     merge_input1.some_column  eq merge_input2.some_column
    where  some_other_column eq 'Y'
    ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe "sure shot success" you mention would be:

```
data merge_output;
 merge
       merge_input1 (in = ina)
       merge_input2 (in = inb)
 ;
 by some_column;
 if ina and inb and some_other_column eq 'Y';
run;
```

Working 14 years with SAS, I believe I never used `where` option on output data set.

The `IF` statement used above (without `THEN`) is called `subsetting IF`, but it's not really subsetting the output (like some post-action), it's simply not allowing some input records to continue through the rest of data step and finally enter output data set.

Regarding option A) using `DELETE` statement is maybe more "telling" what you're doing then `IF` statement and can be used without `OUTPUT` statement, so you can also be more explicit in what your doing like this:

```
data merge_output;
 merge
       merge_input1 (in = ina)
       merge_input2 (in = inb)
 ;
 by some_column;
 if ina and inb; /* "inner join" */
 if some_other_column ne 'Y' then delete; /* subset */
run;
```

In my experience it's `OUTPUT` statement that often leads to forgetting to add it to all the `IF .. THEN .. ELSE..` branches to get expected results. The rule is that once you use OUTPUT statement, there's no automatic output of records at the end of data step, so you have to take care of all the records you need.
So I try to only use `OUTPUT` statement when using multiple output data sets.